# Remove duplicated SUM subquery in Entity Framework Core query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following LINQ code:

```
return from policy in db.Policy.Include(it => it.LedgerLines)
       let balance = policy.LedgerLines.Sum(it => it.Amount)
       where balance > 0m && balance < 5m
       select policy;
```

This gets translated to

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM [Policy] AS [p]
LEFT JOIN [PolicyLedger] AS [p0] ON [p].[Id] = [p0].[PolicyId]
WHERE (((SELECT SUM([p1].[Amount])
         FROM [PolicyLedger] AS [p1]
         WHERE [p].[Id] = [p1].[PolicyId]) > 0.0)) 
   AND ((SELECT SUM([p2].[Amount])
         FROM [PolicyLedger] AS [p2]
         WHERE [p].[Id] = [p2].[PolicyId]) < 5.0)
ORDER BY [p].[Id], [p0].[Id]
```

Is there any way to only execute the `SUM([p1].[Amount])` subquery once?

(EF Core 3.1)

Comment: Can you start from the `LedgerLine` entities instead?

Comment: Interesting idea, @Progman - I tried starting from the ledger lines and grouping by policy id, but I'm getting an error from EF core saying it can't do something about the grouping part. Also, I don't want to make a very obscure query just to remove that subquery - I'd rather have it slower than too complicated.

Comment: What happens if you remove the `Include`

Comment: Not much @Charlieface -- the SQL gets changed a bit (the JOIN is removed) but the two SUM subqueries remain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
let balance = policy.LedgerLines.Sum(it => it.Amount)
```

which is the equivalent of intermediate projection clearly indicates the intent to reuse the expression.

But EF Core query translator puts a lot of efforts to produce "pretty" queries by eliminating subqueries as much as possible. Unfortunately in this case it seems to go too much in that regard.

With that being said, you can consider it to be a translation defect, leave the LINQ query "as is" and wait for improved translation - EFC 5.x doesn't improve that, may be EFC 6.0 or later, if ever.

But here is one not so distracting trick to let EFC 3.1 / 5.x generate `JOIN` to `GROUP BY` subquery and reuse the `SUM` expression.

The only change to the original LINQ query is to replace the above `let` statement with the following

```
from balance in policy.LedgerLines
    .GroupBy(it => it.PolicyId)
    .Select(g => g.Sum(it => it.Amount))
```

which gets translated to

```sql
SELECT ...
FROM [Policy] AS [p]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT SUM([p0].[Amount]) AS [c], [p0].[PolicyId]
    FROM [PolicyLedger] AS [p0]
    GROUP BY [p0].[PolicyId]
) AS [t] ON [p].[Id] = [t].[PolicyId]
LEFT JOIN [PolicyLedger] AS [p1] ON [p].[Id] = [p1].[PolicyId]
WHERE ([t].[c] > 0.0) AND ([t].[c] < 5.0)
ORDER BY [p].[Id], [p1].[Id]
```

Comment: Wow, that's a fantastic trick, thank you -- I'm going to give it some more thought on whether what it does is clear enough (I might have to add some comments) but it definitely does what I asked for.

Answer (score 4):

You could start your query from the `LedgerLine` entity and use a `GroupBy()` to build the sum of the `Amount` column for each policy. However, you can't group on a navigation property, so you have to group on the `PolicyId` instead. This means you need to join the `PolicyId` column with the `Policies` table/DbSet afterwards to get the actual `Policy` entity (with any required included collection properties).

The code can look like this:

```
var result = context.LedgerLines
                .Include(it => it.Policy)
                .GroupBy(it => it.PolicyId)
                .Select(it => new {
                    policyId = it.Key,
                    sum = it.Sum(a => a.Amount)
                })
                .Join(context.Policies.Include(it => it.LedgerLines),
                    it => it.policyId,
                    it => it.Id,
                    (a,b) => new {
                        a.sum,
                        policy=b
                    })
                .Where(it => it.sum > 0m && it.sum < 5m)
                .Select(it => it.policy)
                .ToList();
```

This will generate a query like this (for MySQL):

```
SELECT `p`.`Id`, `p`.`Name`, `l0`.`Id`, `l0`.`Amount`, `l0`.`PolicyId`
FROM (
    SELECT `l`.`PolicyId`, SUM(`l`.`Amount`) AS `c`
    FROM `LedgerLines` AS `l`
    GROUP BY `l`.`PolicyId`
) AS `t`
INNER JOIN `Policies` AS `p` ON `t`.`PolicyId` = `p`.`Id`
LEFT JOIN `LedgerLines` AS `l0` ON `p`.`Id` = `l0`.`PolicyId`
WHERE (CAST(`t`.`c` AS decimal(18, 2)) > 0) AND (CAST(`t`.`c` AS decimal(18, 2)) < 5)
ORDER BY `p`.`Id`, `l0`.`Id`
```

As you see only one `SUM()` call is used, but I'm unsure about the performance as you `JOIN` over the `LedgerLines` table twice, not to mention that this code looks weird and cumbersome.

Comment: You are absolutely right - I will accept this as the answer tomorrow, if nothing better comes up, but I will leave the code as it is since I think the result is definitely more complicated to understand than the original (and potentially also slower).

Comment: Was thinking of that, downside is you need the join and groupby. But it does look more efficient. I would remove the extra `Include` like this `.Join(context.Policies,`